# Position as time on a clock based on the coordinates

Tags: java, python, geometry

Based on the x and y coordinates, I need to implement a function like

```
int getArea(double xcoord, double ycoord , double radius)
```

to get the rough time on the clock. Rough Time means the time on the clock in full hours. So in this case 1 o'clock, 2 o'clock, etc... If the coordinates are outside of the radius, the function should return -1.

Or to be more graphic: Imagine the second Hunger Games movie/book. You have 12 different areas, sorted like a clock. And you enter the coordinates of a tribute into the function, as well as the radius of the arena and in return you want to have the area the tribute is currently in.

So what I managed to figure out is how to check, whether the position is on the clock or not

```
if(Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2) < Math.pow(radius,2))
```

Also, I have a little piece that calculates the sectors:

```
int sectors = 12;
double angle = 2*Math.PI/sectors;
double x_sectors[] = new double[sectors];
double y_sectors[] = new double[sectors];
for(int i = 0; i<sectors; i++){
    x_sectors[i] = Math.cos(i*angle)*radius;
    y_sectors[i] = Math.sin(i*angle)*radius;
}
```

But I'm stuck with a method how to check in which sector the given coordinates are.

Comment: Okay give me some time. I'll do this one for you sir!

Comment: @bot that would be so nice! I'm really stuck with this one :c

Comment: Enough of the sarcasm. What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Well, i managed to check wether the coordinates are on the clock or not. And i have a function that "marks" the 12 sectors on the clock. But I have no clue how to start with the function that checks in wich sector the coordinates are.

Comment: Post whatever you tried as part of your question, please!

Comment: I think what @bot is trying to tell you is that your question is not appropriate for StackOverflow. Questions that ask us to do your work are not taken very well here. You have to show your code, explain exactly what you expect the output to be and what the problem is, and also add any errors that you get if you get them.

Comment: This is more of a math problem really (and a basic one at that). Perhaps the folks in the Math SE could help? (Better wording the question would help a lot in any case.)

Comment: Is it better that way? Sorry, english isn't my native language but i tried my best with the wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use the [Math.atan2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29) method and shift the range of its angle:

```
int getArea(double xcoord, double ycoord , double radius) {
    if(xcoord*xcoord + ycoord*ycoord > radius*radius)
        return -1;
    double angle = Math.PI/2 - Math.atan2(ycoord, xcoord); // Need to suptract the angle from Pi/2 because we want 0 rad to be at +y axis instead of +x axis
    if(angle < 0) // Math.atan2 gives angle in range -Pi/2 to Pi/2 so need to shift it to range 0 to 2*Pi
        angle = 2*Math.PI + angle;
    int segments = 12;
    double angle_one_segment = 2*Math.PI/segments;
    return 1 + (int)(angle/angle_one_segment); // From 12 o'clock to 1 o'clock it's first sector (exactly 12 belongs to 1st sector) and so on. If point (x, y) lies exactly at the boundary between 2 sectors it belongs to the higher one
}
```

[See it run with some testcases on ideone.](http://ideone.com/leps1k)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.hypot()` and `Math.atan2()` methods to perform calculations in polar coordinates by given x and y:

```
if (Math.hypot(x, y) > radius)  
   return -1;                      // out of the circle
double theta = Math.atan2(x, y);
if (theta < 0)
   theta += Math.PI * 2d;
int sector = (int)(theta / Math.PI / 2d * 12d) + 1; // number of one of 12 sectors enumerated from 1
```

Comment: I just benchmarked the line `Math.hypot(x,y) > r` against `x*x + y*y > r*r` and the latter one is approximately a factor 180 faster on my system so I will use my version. Calculating the squareroot is really expensive and shouid be avoided if not necessary. See http://ideone.com/3hCKhC for my testcode

Comment: @halex okay :) its main purpose is to protect from overflow.

Comment: @halex in your benchmark `res = x * x + y * y > r * r` is very likely to be inlined since x, y, and r are constant values :) That is why it performs so fast.

Comment: You are right but the advance is still a an order of magnitude with the following code: http://ideone.com/p8WRwC

Comment: I just was interested in comparing the alternatives and love doing some small preformance tests :)